# How to get the IDs of the channels to which I'm a subscriber?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I would like to know how do I get the IDs of the channels I subscribed to. I don't intent to obtain the subscribers of my channel. I wish to retrieve the channels to which I am subscriber, obviously, using the YouTube Data API. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's the [`Subscriptions.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) API endpoint. You should invoke it with its request parameter `mine` set to `true`:

> [**`mine`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#mine) boolean
> This parameter can only be used in a properly [authorized request](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication). Set this parameter's value to `true` to retrieve a feed of the authenticated user's subscriptions.

Do note that for you to access the list of your subscriptions you'll have to invoke the endpoint upon completing successfully an OAuth 2 authentication/authorization flow.

Comment: Upon you mentioning your programming language/environment, I'll be able to provide you more details about the things implied.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Flutter is my chosen language.

Comment: And Android Studio the IDE.

Comment: Sorry, @Sergio, Flutter and Dart are too exotic to me. Therefore, cannot concretely help you further. I'll indicate though the YouTube Data API's official document [Client Libraries](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/libraries); you can look up for these two recommended Dart entries: [Google APIs Client Libraries for Dart (beta)](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/googleapis) and [Dart samples](https://github.com/dart-lang/googleapis_examples). Unfortunately, the sample code part does not include code exercising the YouTube Data API.